# Is mounting /boot in /etc/fstab automatically necessary?

Tags: debian, partition, fstab, disk-encryption

Hello members of StackExchange,

I am running a Debian 8.0 server with Full-Disk-Encryption and while I was doing some hardening I went through the `/etc/fstab` and I was wondering if some partitions were really necessary to be mounted automatically.

After some [research](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125183/is-boot-partition-needed-after-os-is-booted) I found out that apparently it is not necessary to auto-mount the `/boot` partition since it is being read otherwise and I would not want some program potentially writing in this rather critical area.

But since my filesystem is encrypted, I am not sure if that is still the case and if in general that answer was correct.

I would be happy if someone could give me an answer on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you trust yourself to remember to mount it when it's necessary to do so? And would you even know when that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/boot` partition, while not strictly need for system startup, is an important one and should be mounted. Let me do two simple examples of when it is needed:

1) **Kernel recompile:** you will find that your boot partition hosts some files called `config-*`. These files describe the kernel configuration, and are re-read when issuing `make menuconfig` (and similar) when recompiling your kernel. While it is true that this is not the only method to store kernel configuration, it surely is one of the most used/common.

2) **Upgrades:** when you upgrade your distro, the packet manager will eventually download a new kernel and install it under `/boot`. If `/boot` is not mounted, these boot files will be placed in the wrong filesystem and Grub will not recognize them.

In the end, while you surely can have a running system without `/boot`, this is **not** a good idea. At least, you should always mount it when needed - if you know that.

Comment: So, would it be an option if I auto-mount it read-only instead and temporarily re-mount it in read-write mode whenever I am doing an update/upgrade?

Comment: Yes, but you had to **remember** to mount it each time it is necessary. As a side note, how do you know **when** is it necessary? While updates are obviously, are you 100% sure that no other processes need write access to /boot partition?

Comment: I have been running a server with `/boot` in read-only for a while and everything seems running fine, but I see your point.
Is there a different way of making sure no process is manipulating this partition (from a security standpoint)?

Comment: A first option is to make all files world-readable but only root-writable. Another option is to use SELINUX to protect the /boot mount point from unwanted writes.

Comment: It actually seems like `/boot` is by default only root-writable. I will check into the second option you mentioned at one point as well. Thanks!